# glassfish asadmin CLI does not accept whitespaces

Tags: glassfish, asadmin

When I want to create a resource of any kind using the asadmin CLI, I run into troubles when I have whitespaces in strings. e.g.:

`asadmin create-jms-resource --restype javax.jms.ConnectionFactory --description "a description" jms/testFactory`

I get an error message saying create-jms-resource only accepts one operand. The same thing also happens when I try to pass properties to the CLI. I already tried all kind of escape-characters, but nothing worked.

What is the correct way to escape whitespaced so that asadmin console will understand it. (I'm working in linux)

Comment: I have no troubles even with the command you provided in your question.  I can run it on both windows and *nix based system. Maybe your problem related to shell? What shell are you using?

Comment: I'm using bash 4.2.25(1) and glassfish 3.1.2.2

Comment: My bash version is 4.2.45 and I'm using the same GF version. No troubles with your command on ubuntu OS. Is it possible that your problem relates to encoding somehow? Is it possible that you are using "wrong" quotation marks like “ instead of "?